# What Join should i have to use in ORACLE?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have 2 tables one contain just the dates such as

table1:
select display_date from dates; --will display the whole month dates(01-31)

```
____________________________
display_date
___________________

01-OCT-14
02-OCT-14
03-OCT-14
```

`.....SO ON`

```
______________________
```

table2:
select display_date, weekday, day, month from employee_Day -- this contains some dates from month (01,04,05, etc..). it wont contain all the dates

```
______________________________________________
|display_date   |  weekday   | day  |  month  |
-----------------------------------------------
01-OCT-14          7           01       10
04-OCT-14          5           04       10
_______________________________________________
```

I need to join those two tables and i have to get the output of all the dates and null values for the records which  i need the output like as shown below

```
_____________________________________________
display_date   |   weekday |  day   | month   |
_______________________________________________

01-OCT-14         7           01      10
02-OCT-14         5           02      10
03-OCT-14         4           03      10
```

i tried full outer join but im getting two display_date columns.Any suggestions ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select a.display_date, b.weelday, b.day, b.month
  from dates a, employee_day b
 where a.display_date=b.display_date(+);
```

Comment: select a.display_date, b.weelday, b.day, b.month from (subquery1) a, (subquery2) b where TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(a.DISPLAY_DATE,'DD-MON-RR'),'DD')= TO_CHAR(b.DAY_NUMBER)(+); -- it is throwing an missing expression error, any idea ? @mark

Comment: I don't see anything off hand, but I don't know what 'subquery1 and 'subquery2' are....  Is there something wrong with the query I provided?

Comment: Please don't use the Oracle proprietary `(+)` operator any more. Use a proper `left outer join` operator. Even Oracle recommends stop using `(+)` in the manual

Answer (score 0):

how about this

```
SELECT t2.display_date,t2.weekday,t2.day,t2.month
FROM table2 t2 JOIN table1
USING (display_date)
```